# How to resolve promises in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a very troublesome time figuring out how to do promises in order. I'm making a chat bot for DiscordApp in Node.js, I have searched plenty on here and Google in general. I've tried using `Promise.all` and a Async function. They have not worked, but I feel I'm doing something wrong.

Currently am back to where I started with my code

```
let emoji = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '6⃣', '7⃣', '8⃣', '9⃣']

msg.channel.send('some message being sent')
  .then(sentMessage => {
    poll.users[msg.author.id].forEach(function(item, index) {
      sentMessage.react(emoji[index])
    })
  })
```

This leads to the reactions on the message sometimes, if not most times, being mixed up. As you can see, the emojis are numbers, so I'd like them to be in sequential order. Since `.react()` is a promise, they randomly resolve so as I said before, the numbers emojis get mixed up. If I was wanting them to resolve in order, how could I do this?

Things I've tried: `Promise.all`

```
msg.channel.send('some message being sent')
  .then(sentMessage => {
    foo(poll, msg, sentMessage, index)
  })

async function foo(poll, msg, embedded, voteCount) {
  return await Promise.all(poll.users[msg.author.id].map(() => {
    embedded.react(nums[voteCount])
  }))
}
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43951755/7636961

Comment: Take a look at it. I think you are looking for this http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this:

```
msg.channel.send('some message being sent')
  .then(sentMessage => {
    const result = poll.users[msg.author.id].reduce((p, c, i) => p.then(() => sentMessage.react(emoji[i])), Promise.resolve());

    result.then(() => {
        console.log('all emojis shall be sent in order');
    });
})
```

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! I'm VERY grateful thank you! Can you explain what `.reduce()` does?

Comment: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control